# Remove content-location response header

Tags: .htaccess, httpresponse

For someone relatively new to web development, I just noticed that there is a response header called "Content-Location" which displays source file (PHP). Now I checked some several other sites, and they don't display this in their response headers. I don't know if it's because of my poorly constructed .htaccess file (used a generator), webhosting provider, CloudFlare, or something completely different that causes this to show.

I'll post the .htaccess file just in case:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
...
RewriteRule ^post/([^/]*)\.php$ /news?post=$1 [L]
...
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

So when going to `https://example.com/news` it will display the following in DevTools:

```
...
content-encoding: br
content-location: news.php
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
...
```

It does this for every page except the index for some reason. I don't want these response headers to show up anywhere. Would be very much appreciated if someone could try and help me out.

**EDIT**

So I tried accessing the `https://example.com/news.php` and then the "Content-Location" doesn't show up. So it probably has something to do with my current `.htaccess` settings.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of trial-and-error, I found my solution by adding the following lines to my `.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I tested this, doesn't work in the same way as you said.